# Increase the Width of a Dropdown List

Tags: .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-controls

How can I increase the width of a DropDownList in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a .CSS file, inline or with a STYLE tag.  You can also do it in the code-behind by setting attributes(DropDownList1.Attribute.Add("style","etc...")).

**CSS:**

```
.ChangeWidth
{
    width:400px;    
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="ChangeWidth" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: i did as you said; there is no change at alll

Comment: Make you sure you rebuild your application and whilst in the browser press Ctrl+F5 to load your current CSS file. Cache is ***** like that. :P

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to  use a dynamic width, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoWidth()
    {
        var maxlength = 0;
        var mySelect = document.getElementById('Select1');
        for (var i=0; i<mySelect.options.length;i++)
        {
            if (mySelect[i].text.length > maxlength)
            {
                maxlength = mySelect[i].text.length;
            }
        }
        mySelect.style.width = maxlength * 10;
    }
</script>
```

And use it like this: `onclick="autoWidth()"`

Comment: select1 is the dropdown value is it?

Comment: Onclick event of dropdown? its says there is no onclick event for dropdown..or its a updatepanel onclick event?

Comment: It's just an example, I use it for other things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" width="50px" runat="server"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the width of a DropDownList by giving
 `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" width="50px" runat="server" width="100px"> 
</asp:DropDownList>`
Or by defining the css file
`.Drop

{
width:100px;
}`